# Package to use for AICc (Akaike Information Criterion corrected) in r

Tags: r

Does anyone know what package to use for AICc (Akaike Information Criterion corrected) in r? I am currently using the package 'MASS' and function 'step' to find the best AIC, but I would like to find the best AICc because my sample size is small.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `MuMIn` wil calculate it with the function `AICc`.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MuMIn/versions/1.43.15/topics/AICc

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately, MuMIn has a hard-coded limit of 30 variables (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114813/error-in-mumin-pdredge-when-using-more-than-30-predictor-variables). Also, it doesn't let you do bi-directional stepwise selection-- the starting model is also the maximum model.

Answer (score -1):

It is build into the R core stats package. No extra packages need to be installed.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/AIC

Comment: That's AIC not AICc, as the question is specifically asking for

Comment: @Umaomamaomao Sorry I see I missed the *corrected* part